# How to enable parallelization in tidymodels stacks::control_stack_grid()

Tags: r, tidymodels, ensemble-learning, r-parsnip

I am attempting to use the [tidymodels stacks](https://stacks.tidymodels.org) package to perform ensemble modeling. Following the instructions provided in [their article](https://stacks.tidymodels.org/articles/basics.html), I was able to reproduce the example successfully.

However, when I added parallelization during hyperparameter tuning for the "knn_res" section of the code:

```
library(doParallel)
library(parallel)
set.seed(2020)
cls <- makePSOCKcluster(parallelly::availableCores())
registerDoParallel(cls)
knn_res <- 
  tune_grid(
    knn_wflow,
    resamples = folds,
    metrics = metric,
    grid = 4,
    control = ctrl_grid
  )
stopCluster(cls)
```

I encountered an error when running the "tree_frogs_model_st" section of the code:

```
tree_frogs_model_st <-
  tree_frogs_data_st %>%
  blend_predictions()
```

The error message states:

```
Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection
```

I believe this issue may be related to the [stacks::control_stack_grid()](https://stacks.tidymodels.org/reference/control_stack.html) function, but I am unsure of how to resolve it. Please advice.

---

**UPDATE (full reprex)**

I excluded the linear model for brevity.

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(stacks)


data("tree_frogs")

# subset the data
tree_frogs <- tree_frogs %>%
  filter(!is.na(latency)) %>%
  select(-c(clutch, hatched))


# some setup: resampling and a basic recipe
set.seed(1)
tree_frogs_split <- initial_split(tree_frogs)
tree_frogs_train <- training(tree_frogs_split)
tree_frogs_test  <- testing(tree_frogs_split)

set.seed(1)
folds <- rsample::vfold_cv(tree_frogs_train, v = 5)

tree_frogs_rec <- 
  recipe(latency ~ ., data = tree_frogs_train)

metric <- metric_set(rmse)

ctrl_grid <- control_stack_grid()
ctrl_res <- control_stack_resamples()


# create a model definition
knn_spec <-
  nearest_neighbor(
    mode = "regression", 
    neighbors = tune("k")
  ) %>%
  set_engine("kknn")

knn_spec
#> K-Nearest Neighbor Model Specification (regression)
#> 
#> Main Arguments:
#>   neighbors = tune("k")
#> 
#> Computational engine: kknn


knn_rec <-
  tree_frogs_rec %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_impute_mean(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())

knn_rec
#> Recipe
#> 
#> Inputs:
#> 
#>       role #variables
#>    outcome          1
#>  predictor          4
#> 
#> Operations:
#> 
#> Dummy variables from all_nominal_predictors()
#> Zero variance filter on all_predictors()
#> Mean imputation for all_numeric_predictors()
#> Centering and scaling for all_numeric_predictors()


knn_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(knn_spec) %>%
  add_recipe(knn_rec)

knn_wflow
#> ══ Workflow ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: nearest_neighbor()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 4 Recipe Steps
#> 
#> • step_dummy()
#> • step_zv()
#> • step_impute_mean()
#> • step_normalize()
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> K-Nearest Neighbor Model Specification (regression)
#> 
#> Main Arguments:
#>   neighbors = tune("k")
#> 
#> Computational engine: kknn

library(doParallel)
#> Loading required package: foreach
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'foreach'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     accumulate, when
#> Loading required package: iterators
#> Loading required package: parallel
library(parallel)
set.seed(2020)
cls <- makePSOCKcluster(parallelly::availableCores())
registerDoParallel(cls)
knn_res <- 
  tune_grid(
    knn_wflow,
    resamples = folds,
    metrics = metric,
    grid = 4,
    control = ctrl_grid
  )
stopCluster(cls)

knn_res
#> # Tuning results
#> # 5-fold cross-validation 
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   splits           id    .metrics         .notes           .predictions      
#>   <list>           <chr> <list>           <list>           <list>            
#> 1 <split [343/86]> Fold1 <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [344 × 5]>
#> 2 <split [343/86]> Fold2 <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [344 × 5]>
#> 3 <split [343/86]> Fold3 <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [344 × 5]>
#> 4 <split [343/86]> Fold4 <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [344 × 5]>
#> 5 <split [344/85]> Fold5 <tibble [4 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [340 × 5]>




# create a model definition -----
svm_spec <- 
  svm_rbf(
    cost = tune("cost"), 
    rbf_sigma = tune("sigma")
  ) %>%
  set_engine("kernlab") %>%
  set_mode("regression")

# extend the recipe
svm_rec <-
  tree_frogs_rec %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_impute_mean(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
  step_corr(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())

# add both to a workflow
svm_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(svm_spec) %>%
  add_recipe(svm_rec)

# tune cost and sigma and fit to the 5-fold cv
set.seed(2020)
cls <- makePSOCKcluster(parallelly::availableCores())
registerDoParallel(cls)
svm_res <- 
  tune_grid(
    svm_wflow, 
    resamples = folds, 
    grid = 6,
    metrics = metric,
    control = ctrl_grid
  )
stopCluster(cls)
svm_res
#> # Tuning results
#> # 5-fold cross-validation 
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   splits           id    .metrics         .notes           .predictions      
#>   <list>           <chr> <list>           <list>           <list>            
#> 1 <split [343/86]> Fold1 <tibble [6 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [516 × 6]>
#> 2 <split [343/86]> Fold2 <tibble [6 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [516 × 6]>
#> 3 <split [343/86]> Fold3 <tibble [6 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [516 × 6]>
#> 4 <split [343/86]> Fold4 <tibble [6 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [516 × 6]>
#> 5 <split [344/85]> Fold5 <tibble [6 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [510 × 6]>


tree_frogs_data_st <- 
  stacks() %>%
  add_candidates(knn_res) %>%
  add_candidates(svm_res)

tree_frogs_data_st
#> # A data stack with 2 model definitions and 10 candidate members:
#> #   knn_res: 4 model configurations
#> #   svm_res: 6 model configurations
#> # Outcome: latency (numeric)


tree_frogs_model_st <-
  tree_frogs_data_st %>%
  blend_predictions()
#> Error in summary.connection(connection): invalid connection

tree_frogs_model_st
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'tree_frogs_model_st' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
#>  os       Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  C.UTF-8
#>  ctype    C.UTF-8
#>  tz       Asia/Tokyo
#>  date     2023-01-27
#>  pandoc   2.14.0.3 @ /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package      * version    date (UTC) lib source
#>  assertthat     0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  backports      1.4.1      2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  broom        * 1.0.1      2022-08-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  butcher        0.1.5      2021-06-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  class          7.3-19     2021-05-03 [4] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  cli            3.6.0      2023-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  codetools      0.2-18     2020-11-04 [4] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  colorspace     2.0-3      2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  crayon         1.5.1      2022-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  DBI            1.1.2      2021-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  dials        * 1.1.0      2022-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  DiceDesign     1.9        2021-02-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  digest         0.6.29     2021-12-01 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  doParallel   * 1.0.17     2022-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  dplyr        * 1.0.9      2022-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  ellipsis       0.3.2      2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  evaluate       0.15       2022-02-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  fansi          1.0.3      2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  fastmap        1.1.0      2021-01-25 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  foreach      * 1.5.2      2022-02-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  fs             1.5.2      2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  furrr          0.3.1      2022-08-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  future         1.25.0     2022-04-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  future.apply   1.9.0      2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  generics       0.1.3      2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  ggplot2      * 3.4.0      2022-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  glmnet         4.1-4      2022-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  globals        0.15.0     2022-05-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  glue           1.6.2      2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  gower          1.0.0      2022-02-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  GPfit          1.0-8      2019-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  gtable         0.3.0      2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  hardhat        1.2.0      2022-06-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  highr          0.9        2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  htmltools      0.5.2      2021-08-25 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  igraph         1.3.1      2022-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  infer        * 1.0.0      2021-08-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  ipred          0.9-12     2021-09-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  iterators    * 1.0.14     2022-02-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  kernlab        0.9-30     2022-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  kknn           1.3.1      2016-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  knitr          1.38       2022-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  lattice        0.20-45    2021-09-22 [4] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  lava           1.6.10     2021-09-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  lhs            1.1.5      2022-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  lifecycle      1.0.3      2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  listenv        0.8.0      2019-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  lubridate      1.8.0      2021-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  magrittr       2.0.3      2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  MASS           7.3-54     2021-05-03 [4] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  Matrix         1.3-4      2021-06-01 [4] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  modeldata    * 0.1.1      2021-07-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  munsell        0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  nnet           7.3-16     2021-05-03 [4] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  parallelly     1.31.1     2022-04-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  parsnip      * 1.0.3      2022-11-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  pillar         1.7.0      2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  pkgconfig      2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  prodlim        2019.11.13 2019-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  purrr        * 0.3.4      2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  R.cache        0.15.0     2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  R.methodsS3    1.8.1      2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  R.oo           1.24.0     2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  R.utils        2.11.0     2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  R6             2.5.1      2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  Rcpp           1.0.10     2023-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  recipes      * 1.0.3      2022-11-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  reprex         2.0.1      2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rlang          1.0.6      2022-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rmarkdown      2.13       2022-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rpart          4.1-15     2019-04-12 [4] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  rsample      * 1.1.1      2022-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rstudioapi     0.13       2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  scales       * 1.2.0      2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  sessioninfo    1.2.2      2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  shape          1.4.6      2021-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  stacks       * 1.0.1      2022-12-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  stringi        1.7.6      2021-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  stringr        1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  styler         1.7.0      2022-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  survival       3.2-13     2021-08-24 [4] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tibble       * 3.1.7      2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  tidymodels   * 0.2.0      2022-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  tidyr        * 1.2.0      2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  tidyselect     1.2.0      2022-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  timeDate       3043.102   2018-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  tune         * 1.0.1      2022-10-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  usethis        2.1.5      2021-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  utf8           1.2.2      2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  vctrs          0.5.1      2022-11-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  withr          2.5.0      2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  workflows    * 1.1.2      2022-11-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  workflowsets * 0.2.1      2022-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  xfun           0.31       2022-05-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  yaml           2.3.5      2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  yardstick    * 1.1.0      2022-09-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#> 
#>  [1] /home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1
#>  [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#>  [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
#>  [4] /usr/lib/R/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reprex (reproducible example)? The goal of a reprex is to make it as easy as possible for me to recreate your problem so that I can fix it: please help me help you!

If you've never heard of a reprex before, start by reading "[What is a reprex](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex#what-is-a-reprex)", and follow the advice further down that page.

Comment: @topepo I updated my OP with full reprex.

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce the issue.

A parallel backend was registered and stacks picks up on that.

The issue is that the cluster is stopped before the blending and it would try to use it. If you move `stopCluster(cls)` to the end, it works.

We *should* be able to understand that some parts should be done in parallel and others might not. I'll add a bug report for that.

The blending and member training can also be done in parallel so, for the time being, move that to the end of the script.

Comment: +1 to Max's recommendation for moving forward for now. Turns out that this can be replicated with tune only, and the failure in stacks is just an instantiation of the same failure—I've filed the issue in tune for now: https://github.com/tidymodels/tune/issues/606